# Nullable foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT Useraccount.Name, Company.Name  
 FROM Useraccount, Company
WHERE Useraccount.CompanyId = Company.ID
```

This statement shows all useraccount-names and the name of their company.

But I also have useraccounts where the companyId is 0 and I'd like to get them displayed too (Name of the company could be an empty string in this case).
How can I do that?

Comment: And don't use `0`. I don't like them but that's what `NULL`is for. You can add an explicit foreign key constraint if you convert the 0s to Nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT 
  Useraccount.Name, 
  Company.Name  
FROM Useraccount
LEFT JOIN Company ON Useraccount.CompanyId = Company.ID;
```

You were `INNER JOIN`ing the two tables with the old `JOIN` syntax. Please avoid this old join syntax and use the ANSI SQL-92 explicit syntax using the `JOIN` keyword. See this for more information:

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

For more info about the different join types:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT JOIN` would do the trick for you:

```
SELECT Useraccount.Name, Company.Name  
FROM Useraccount
 LEFT JOIN Company ON Useraccount.CompanyId = Company.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
SELECT Useraccount.Name, Company.Name  
 FROM Useraccount, Company
WHERE Useraccount.CompanyId = Company.ID or Useraccount.CompanyId =0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use **LEFT JOIN**, you will get all rows from left table irrespective of the matching status of rows.

```
SELECT 
Useraccount.Name AS UserAccountName, 
Company.Name AS CompanyName 
FROM Useraccount
LEFT JOIN Company 
ON Useraccount.CompanyId = Company.ID;
```